# Find the most recent date from an Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, date

How to find the most recent date from an array like the one below?

```
Tue Jun 2 17:59:54 GMT+0200 2013
Tue Jun 5 18:00:10 GMT+0200 2013
Tue Jun 1 12:27:14 GMT+0200 2013
Tue Jun 3 17:26:58 GMT+0200 2013
Tue Jun 9 17:27:49 GMT+0200 2013
Tue Jun 1 13:27:39 GMT+0200 2015
Tue Jun 3 12:27:59 GMT+0200 2013
Tue Jun 6 15:27:22 GMT+0200 2014
Tue Jun 2 17:27:30 GMT+0200 2014
```

Comment: Are the dates in your array Date objects or strings?  You just need to sort your Date objects by the time property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array is full of AS3 native `Date` objects, you could simply do this:

```
array.sortOn("time",Array.DESCENDING);

trace("Most Recent:",array[0]);
```

You cannot use `array.sort` (unless you use the `Array.NUMERIC` flag) because it will sort the string representation of the date.  So all your days of the week would then be grouped together instead of the actual date.

---

If your dates are strings, then you will need to convert them to Date objects prior to sorting:

```
//assuming your posted array is in a var called 'stringArray'

var dateArray:Array = []; //a new array to hold the converted strings

for(var i:int=0;i<stringArray.length;i++){
    dateArray.push(new Date(stringArray[i]));
}

dateArray.sortOn("time",Array.DESCENDING);
trace("Most Recent Date:",dateArray[0]);
```

---

To show this in a concrete example,  here is your posted dates - copy paste this code to produce the same results:

```
var arr:Array = new Array(
    new Date("Tue Jun 2 17:59:54 GMT+0200 2013"),
    new Date("Tue Jun 5 18:00:10 GMT+0200 2013"),
    new Date("Tue Jun 1 12:27:14 GMT+0200 2013"),
    new Date("Tue Jun 3 17:26:58 GMT+0200 2013"),
    new Date("Tue Jun 9 17:27:49 GMT+0200 2013"),
    new Date("Tue Jun 1 13:27:39 GMT+0200 2015"),
    new Date("Tue Jun 3 12:27:59 GMT+0200 2013"),
    new Date("Tue Jun 6 15:27:22 GMT+0200 2014"),
    new Date("Tue Jun 2 17:27:30 GMT+0200 2014")
);

arr.sort(Array.DESCENDING);

trace("SORT:");
traceDates();

arr.sortOn("time",Array.DESCENDING);
trace("\nSORT ON:");
traceDates();



function traceDates(){
    for(var i:int=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        trace(" ",arr[i].fullYear + "-" + arr[i].month + "-" + arr[i].day);
    }
}

//OUTPUT:
/*
SORT:
  2013-5-3
  2013-5-0
  2013-5-0
  2013-5-6
  2013-5-1
  2013-5-1
  2014-5-1
  2015-5-1 //most recent date, second to LAST item in the array
  2014-5-5

SORT ON:
  2015-5-1  //June 1st is the most recent date (first item in the array)
  2014-5-5
  2014-5-1
  2013-5-0
  2013-5-3
  2013-5-1
  2013-5-1
  2013-5-0
  2013-5-6
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Are they [Date](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html) objects?
If so, you can compare the [time](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#time) property of each. It will give you the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. The highest number will be the most recent.

Something along these lines:

```
var mostRecentDate:Date = dateArray[0];
for(var i:int = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++){
    if(dateArray[i].time > mostRecentDate.time){
        mostRecentDate = dateArray[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooh, I like the idea of just sorting the array based on the time property better. Didn't think of that.

Comment: You could just use the sortOn method of the array:  `array.sortOn("time")`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Date object do sort themselves pretty well, they also support comparison operators all that without using any of their property. For example: "dateArray[i].time > mostRecentDate.time" could be simply "dateArray[i] > mostRecentDate"

Comment: I don't think you can do a plain `array.sort` on an array of dates.

Comment: they do indeed sort like numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Date objects act like simple Number when it comes to sorting or comparison. All you have to do is treat them like Numbers. So taken from Cadin answer:

```
dateArray.sort();    
var oldestDate:Date = dateArray[0];
```

Will get you the oldest Date while:

```
dateArray.sort(Array.DESCENDING);    
var mostRecentDate:Date = dateArray[0];
```

Will get you the most recent one.

For LDMS, this is what I got:

```
var firstdate:Date = new Date();
var seconddate:Date = new Date();
var thirddate:Date = new Date();
seconddate.time = firstdate.time + 5000000;
thirddate.time = firstdate.time + 50000000;
trace(seconddate > firstdate)//true
trace(firstdate > seconddate)//false
trace(seconddate.time > firstdate.time)//true
var array:Array = [thirddate, firstdate, seconddate];
trace(array)
//Wed Jun 3 03:37:40 GMT-0400 2015,Tue Jun 2 13:44:20 GMT-0400 2015,Tue Jun 2 15:07:40 GMT-0400 2015
array.sort();
trace(array)
//Tue Jun 2 13:44:20 GMT-0400 2015,Tue Jun 2 15:07:40 GMT-0400 2015,Wed Jun 3 03:37:40 GMT-0400 2015
array.sort(Array.DESCENDING);
trace(array)
//Wed Jun 3 03:37:40 GMT-0400 2015,Tue Jun 2 15:07:40 GMT-0400 2015,Tue Jun 2 13:44:20 GMT-0400 2015
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need to use `sortOn("time",Array.DESCENDING)` instead of `sort(Array.DESCENDING)`.   Have you actually tried it?

Comment: It only works for you because the string representation of the dates in your small sample data happen to sort the same as if they were numeric. Since the OP mistakenly accepted your answer, you should at least correct it for future visitors who won't bother to look at anything but the accepted answer.   use `sortOn("time",Array.DESCENDING)` like I suggest, or add the `Array.NUMERIC` flag if using sort.  `sort(Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING)`

Answer (score -1):

[Sort the array](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sort()) and grab the first (descending) or last (ascending) element.

Edit: 2 down-votes because I didn't provide an example, or because people don't know you can sort dates? This works:

```
var dates:Array = [
    "Tue Jun 2 17:59:54 GMT+0200 2013",
    "Tue Jun 5 18:00:10 GMT+0200 2013",
    "Tue Jun 1 12:27:14 GMT+0200 2013",
    "Tue Jun 3 17:26:58 GMT+0200 2013",
    "Tue Jun 9 17:27:49 GMT+0200 2013",
    "Tue Jun 1 13:27:39 GMT+0200 2015",
    "Tue Jun 3 12:27:59 GMT+0200 2013",
    "Tue Jun 6 15:27:22 GMT+0200 2014",
    "Tue Jun 2 17:27:30 GMT+0200 2014"
].map(function(s:String, i:int, a:Array):Date {
    return new Date(s);
}).sort(Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);

var latest:Date = dates[0]; // Mon Jun 1 07:27:39 GMT-0400 2015
```

The problem is the OP did not make it clear what kind of data they are working with (strings or `Date` objects) so the exact solution code is unknown.